# Obtain how many steps back from latest page while navigating in browser history?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

In context of the HTML5 history API, how do I retrieve the current depth, while I'm navigating in history, ie, how many steps far am I from the latest view or the max no of forwards i can do using forward button on browser at current stage ?

Or at least if I can get a boolean indicating whether I'm currently on latest view or some older views(navigated to using back button) ?

Answer (score 1):

The history API can provide the length but it does not tell you how far/deep you are in.

You may want to try passing additional info to the pushstate to get this information. Something like [this](https://github.com/balupton/history.js#working-with-historyjs).

Comment: Could you please share how to do that exactly. I did tried switching to hisotry.js but the major problem that arose was that onpopstate was fired even for pushstate operation & i could figure out any way to identify if it was called as a result of popup or push operation on the history stack!? Kindly support answer with some details about how to do that exactly..

Comment: hey nitesh, could you indicate how to do that exactly ? or point to some relevant link ?

Comment: I have created a [sample](http://niteshandbhavya.110mb.com/stackoverflow/12143981/) but this is not completely fool proof.